# How to disable Compiled Configuration?

Tags: magento2, cache, configuration, compiler

I was trying to disable all my caches, then I noticed that one of my Magento 2 installations has a particular cache type called **Compiled Config**.

I don't want to use my installation compiled, I wan't to disable the compilation to not see this cache option, how could I disable the compilation?

[image: Magento2 compiled configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Run below command

```
php bin/magento cache:disable compiled_config
```

Comment: I want to disable the compilation in my installation instead of disabling the cache type.